# Split strings with an "Enter"

Tags: java, android, string, split

I have code that splits a string into 3 strings, then prints them. I want each one to be separated by the equivalent of an "Enter". Here's the code:

```
String accval = text;
        try {
            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                    new FileWriter("sdcard/YS Data/Accelerometer.html",
                            true)));
            String[] tempArr = accval.split("\\s+");
            String x = tempArr[0] + "_"; //I want the enter to be where the underlines are:
            String y = tempArr[1] + "_";
            String z = tempArr[2] + "_";

            for (String a : tempArr) {
                writer.println("<h3 style=padding-left:20px;>" + x + y
                        + z + "</h3><br>");
            }

            writer.flush();
            writer.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // put notification here later!!!
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

This outputs:

```
x=-0.125_y=0.9375_z=0.375
x=-0.125_y=0.9375_z=0.375
```

with the strings separated by underscores.

However, I want it to look like this:

```
x=-0.125 
y=0.9375 
z=0.375
x=-0.125 
y=0.9375 
z=0.375
```

Thanks for any help.

*EDIT:*

I've implemented the answer of @Julius in the following code that prints how I wanted it:

Code:

```
 String accval = text;
        try {
            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                    new FileWriter("sdcard/YS Data/Accelerometer.html",
                            true)));
            String[] tempArr = accval.split("\\s+");
            String x = tempArr[0];
            String y = tempArr[1];
            String z = tempArr[2];

            for (String a : tempArr) {
                writer.println("<h3 style=padding-left:20px;>" + x + "<br>" + y + <br>
                        + z + "</h3><br>");
            }

            writer.flush();
            writer.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // put notification here later!!!
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Which prints:

```
x=0.25
y=125
z=1.23

x=0.125
y=725
z=0.935
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you want the line returns to be displayed in the browser, this is the way to go:

```
writer.println("<h3 style=padding-left:20px;>" + x + "<br/>" + y + "<br/>" + z + "<br/></h3>");
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use

`System.getProperty("line.separator")`

to get a line separator.

Comment: Most generic and best way to escape from special cases.

Answer (score 1):

You could explicitly write CR+LF as in the other answers here. You can also use the default line break by just using `println` separately for each item, e.g.:

```
for (String a : tempArr) {
    writer.println("<h3 style=padding-left:20px;>");
    writer.println(x);
    writer.println(y);
    writer.println(z);
    writer.println("</h3><br>");
}
```

This is slightly more verbose but won't run into inconsistent line-break issues on systems where CRLF is not the default line ending.

Note, however, that the linebreaks in the HTML probably won't be rendered, unless your CSS specifies that they should be. You *probably* want to just write a "<br>" tag after each element instead of an actual line break, e.g.:

```
    writer.println("<h3 style=padding-left:20px;>");
    writer.println(x + "<br>");
    writer.println(y + "<br>");
    writer.println(z + "<br>");
    writer.println("</h3><br>");
```

You wouldn't have to use `println` for this (you could use `print` or just concatenate as you were doing before), but it does make the generated source a bit more readable.

Off topic, your use of linebreaks in an "<h3>" header tag isn't really semantically appropriate. A "<div>" with appropriate styling would be a more accurate representation, unless these are actually serving as section headers.

Comment: Thank You :) if I could accept both Jason C's and Julius' answers I would, they both work fine. Thanks again

Comment: Re: line breaks. I'm saving it to a html file, and I've just started java and am doing this for a project so my code is kind of thrown together. Thanks for pointing out though :)

Answer (score 0):

`"\r\n"` is the correct string for a line break on Windows systems; `"\n"` is correct on Linux and other Unix-based systems.  This will work on either type of system:

```
String newline = String.format("%n");
```

which will set `newline` to `"\r\n"` or `"\n"` as appropriate (or perhaps some other sequence on some OS's from a different planet :)

**EDIT:**`%n` by definition inserts `System.getProperty("line.separator")` as noted in another answer.  So these are equivalent.